# allow remote access to my WAMP or XAMPP server

Tags: xampp, wampserver, lan

I have developed a site  it's working locally using the WAMP . i need to implement accessing localhost (wamp) from another computer over LAN 
I follow this  toturial 
http://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall
to open tcp port 80 in windows firewall 
But when i search from another computer by write my computer ipv4 
I still saw " the page not found " 
Kindly Can you please help me to figure out what i have to do ? or how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are typing "localhost" on the other computer. But localhost is just what it sounds like, and it will send the request to itself, not the remote computer. What you need to do is type in the IP address of the computer running the webserver. Since you're running Windows, go to your start screen/menu, search for "command prompt" (no quotes), press enter to launch it, type ipconfig into the black box which appears, and press enter. Look for whichever adapter has an IPv4 address (it will most likely take the form of 192.168.X.X). Type that IP address into the URL bar of the browser on the other computer.

Comment: Have you tried pinging the webserver (ping <ip address>), to make sure you have network connectivity directly between the computers?